# Div tabs with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, styles

I organized my tabs this way:

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li class="selected"><a href="#div1">DIV1</a></li>
    <li class><a href="#div2">DIV2</a></li>
    <li class><a href="#div3">DIV3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs_content">
    <div id="div1" style="display: block;"><textarea name="div1" rows="7" cols="108"></textarea></div>
    <div id="div2" style="display: none;"><textarea name="div2" rows="7" cols="108"></textarea></div>
    <div id="div3" style="display: none;"><textarea name="div3" rows="7" cols="108"></textarea></div>
</div>
```

I would like that when I press one of the link inside the `<li>` element,
the corrispondend Div become visible with `display: block` and the others are changed to `display: none`

Also I would like to do the same with the "selected" class on the clicked `<li>` element.

Is this possible?

I tried with:

```
function selectTab(src)
{
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(src).style.display = 'block';
}
```

It works if I pass the ID by reference with `onclick=""` but I would like to avoid this.

Solution:

```
function selectTab(source, parent)
{
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(source).style.display = 'block';

    var elements = [].slice.apply(document.getElementsByClassName('selected'));
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].className = '';
    }

    parent.className = 'selected';
}
```

Comment: Resetting all elements before you set them correctly may cause flickering. Also, getting the elements by ID every click is rather unnecessary. Also, you can pass on `this` as argument, on which you can get the id of that element by `that.id` or `that.href` for the id in the href tag. Take a look at my question for a more elegant answer if you ain't using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'll study your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly this is what you want, cross-browser (IE5.5+)

CSS

```
.selected {
    background-color: green;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li class="selected"><a href="#div1">DIV1</a>

    </li>
    <li class><a href="#div2">DIV2</a>

    </li>
    <li class><a href="#div3">DIV3</a>

    </li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs_content">
    <div id="div1">
        <textarea name="div1" rows="7" cols="108"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" class="hide">
        <textarea name="div2" rows="7" cols="108"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="div3" class="hide">
        <textarea name="div3" rows="7" cols="108"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var tabs = document.getElementById("tabs"),
    tabs_content = document.getElementById("tabs_content"),
    divs = tabs_content.getElementsByTagName("div"),
    divsLength = divs.length,
    lis = tabs.getElementsByTagName("li"),
    lisLength = lis.length;

tabs.onclick = function (evt) {
    var e = evt || window.event,
        target = e.target || e.srcElement,
        href,
        id,
        index,
        div;

    if (target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "A") {
        for (index = 0; index < lisLength; index += 1) {
            lis[index].className = "";
        }

        target.parentNode.className = "selected";
        href = target.attributes.href.nodeValue;
        if (href && href.charAt(0) === "#") {
            id = href.slice(1);
            for (index = 0; index < divsLength; index += 1) {
                div = divs[index];
                if (id === div.id) {
                    div.className = "";
                } else {
                    div.className = "hide";
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/fR8pq/)

Comment: Where do I have to place the onload function in the html?

Comment: There is no `onload` function in either the question or answers. I assume that you are asking another question, for which you should create a new question or search existing Q&As.

Answer (score 0):

Your `selectTab` function needs to be necessarily bound to the `click` event on those list elements. There's no other way you can do it. Your code is good enough. You can simplify things using JQuery as well, as some other answer here points out.

Okay, do this:

In your HTML, add "tab" class to each of the  tags.

```
<li class="selected"><a class="tab" href="#div1">DIV1</a></li>
<li class><a class="tab" href="#div2">DIV2</a></li>
<li class><a class="tab" href="#div3">DIV3</a></li>
```

In your jquery,

```
$('.tab').click(function(){
var displaydiv = $(this).attr('href');
$('#div1').hide();
$('#div2').hide();
$('#div3').hide();
$(this).show();
$('"'+displaydiv+'"').show();
$(this).parent().attr('class','selected');
})
```

Comment: The problem is how to change the "selected" class name on the corrispondent <li>. I can't find a way.

Comment: Ok I gt it working with Javascript only, as I would not like to use JQuery. But I will give it a try :) Look above for my solution.

Comment: If you got the `a`-tag, you can get to the `li`-tag using the `.parentNode` property.

Comment: What do you think this means? $(this).parent().attr('class','selected');

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li class="selected"><a onclick="showTab(this);" href="#div1">DIV1</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="showTab(this);" href="#div2">DIV2</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="showTab(this);" href="#div3">DIV3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs_content">
    <div id="div1" style="display: block;"><textarea name="div1" rows="7" cols="108"></textarea></div>
    <div id="div2" style="display: none;"><textarea name="div2" rows="7" cols="108"></textarea></div>
    <div id="div3" style="display: none;"><textarea name="div3" rows="7" cols="108"></textarea></div>
</div>
```

Use the following javascript:

```
function showTab(a)
{
    var id = a.href.replace('#','');
    var tabs = document.getElementById('tabs_content').getElementsByTagName('div');
    var index = -1;
    for(var i=0,n=tabs.length;i<n;i+=1)
    {
        var t = tabs[i];
        if(t.id === id)
        {
            t.style.display = 'block';
            index = i;
        }
        else
        {
            t.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    var links = document.getElementById('tabs').getElementsByTagName('li');
    for(var i=0,n=links.length;i<n;i+=1)
    {
        links[i].setAttribute('class', index === i ? 'selected' : '');
    }
}
```

Of course you could also first cache your menu and tabs, that way you can keep a variable. This is the proper way:

```
function Menu()
{
    var self = this;
    self.links = document.getElementById('tabs').getElementsByTagName('a');
    self.tabs = document.getElementById('tabs_content').getElementsByTagName('div');
    self.selectedIndex = 0;
    self.n = self.links.length;

    for(var i=0;i<self.n;i+=1)
    {
        // Set onclick for every link in the tabs-menu
        self.links[i].onclick = function(ind){return function(){self.update(ind);};}(i);
    }

    self.update = function(ind)
    {
        // Hide previous tab
        self.links[self.selectedIndex].parentNode.setAttribute('class', '');
        self.tabs[self.selectedIndex].style.display = 'none';

        // Select and show clicked tab
        self.selectedIndex = ind;
        self.links[self.selectedIndex].parentNode.setAttribute('class', 'selected');
        self.tabs[self.selectedIndex].style.display = 'block';
    };
}
setTimeout(function(){new Menu();},1);
```

Check out the jsfiddle for the Menu class in action: http://jsfiddle.net/3vf4A/1/. Note that even if Javascript is disabled, the `a`-tag will still get you to the correct area by scrolling to it automatically.

Comment: Such a really long Javascript is too long to be simple

Comment: The Menu-class is just more than double the size of your jQuery solution. However, it handles the switching less brutal and the performance should be way higher. And even though it takes some extra code, using a bit of OOP it still remains quite maintainable and easy to read.